# Center a circle in a canvas with a % width

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

It does not seem that I can draw a circle in the center of a canvas, if the canvas has a width % such as %33.3333 (the idea is to have 3 beside each other).

Why is this?
http://jsfiddle.net/n302nsbh/2/

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    <canvas class="myCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.myCanvas {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```
 var canvas = $('.myCanvas');
 canvas.width = canvas.width();
 canvas.height = canvas.height();

 var context = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
 var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
 var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
 var radius = canvas.height/2;

 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = 'blue';
 context.fill();
 context.lineWidth = 5;
 context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
 context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `canvas` variable is not your canvas object, but is a *jQuery* instance, so when you set your width and height properties they are not correctly going through jQuery correctly to your actual canvas element.

Change your first lines to something like:

```
var jQCanvas = $('.myCanvas');
var canvas = jQCanvas[0];
canvas.width = jQCanvas.width();
canvas.height = jQCanvas.height();
// etc.
```

Here's a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/n302nsbh/8/

---

As others have mentioned, you can offset the `lineWidth` from your radius to ensure it's all on screen inclusive of the border. I've added that to the fiddle, but that's not the real reason it's not centering.

Comment: @CupawnTae Good catch. I visually glazed over the context methods as `canvas.` instead of `context.` I updated the answer for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that jQuery is not correctly computing width and height of the canvas element. In your case I think it would be better to use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of `$`. Both of them have similar functionality, but `document.querySelector` is native, which means you don't need to include whole jQuery to do just this one thing. `document.querySelector` returns a DOM object, which doesn't have `width` and `height` methods, but does have `width` and `height` properties.

Corrected code:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector(".myCanvas");

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = canvas.height /2;
```

See also [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n302nsbh/9/).

Answer (score 0):

A canvas element is very much like an image, just because you change the visible width doesn't mean you changed the internal dimensions (and you haven't)

http://jsfiddle.net/n302nsbh/7/

This example works because it ignores that you're scaling it to 33%.

```
 var canvas = $('.myCanvas');

 var context = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');
 var centerX = canvas.get(0).width / 2;
 var centerY = canvas.get(0).height / 2;
 var radius = canvas.get(0).height/2;
```

Comment: Except that he was attempting to set the internal dimensions too, he was just setting it in the wrong place, as explained in @rgthree's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34227337/1469259

Comment: I didn't get that from the wording of his question but I guess I could have assumed that form the code.

Comment: Well that's the thing - if the OP had realized what the issue was in the first place, he'd probably never have asked the question at all.